# Android: Get current foreground activity every 10 seconds once user clicks button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've read from the Android documentation (Android newbie here), but generally a lot of articles and questions on how to get current foreground activities (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115493/android-dynamicly-get-the-current-activity-in-foreground), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667022/android-is-application-running-in-background), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166961/determining-the-current-foreground-application-from-a-background-task-or-service)) and how to get commands running every X minutes/seconds (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163631/start-service-every-10-seconds), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221996/how-do-i-repeat-a-method-every-10-minutes-after-a-button-press-and-end-it-on-ano), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535733/display-data-after-every-10-seconds-in-android), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902600/how-to-execute-a-function-every-two-seconds-in-java-on-android)), but I can't seem to manage to combine the two **in between button clicks**.

The purpose of this task is, once the user clicks a *Start* button, the current activity is displayed on screen, through a `Toast`, every 10 seconds. Once the user clicks *Stop*, the `Toast`s stop popping up.

I managed to get the current activity be displayed every 10 seconds by using the following code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Intent i = new Intent(context, SimpleService.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
// Start every 10 seconds
alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10*1000, pintent);
```

where `SimpleService` is a `Service` that contains the following code in its `onStartCommand`

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE); 
// get the info from the currently running task
List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
String curAct = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getPackageName(); 
Toast.makeText(context, curAct, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

However, the moment I try to put my lovely 10-second runner in between `onClick` functions, this line gives me an error under `getService`:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
```

Saying `The method getService(Context, int, Intent, int) in the type PendingIntent is not applicable to the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}, int, Intent, int)`.

I get the same thing if I try to put the `ActivityManager` in `Runnable`s and other methods, but they never work if the function is in the `ClickListener` (always same error).

What should I do? How could I get the `Toast`s to appear every 10 seconds with the current foreground activity after the user clicks the start, and stop it after the user clicks the stop?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using this in

```
PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
```

create a private member of your activity for context like this:

```
private Context myContext;
```

in onCreate instantiate it with:

```
myContext= getApplicationContext();
```

and then use this context in getService:

```
PendingIntent.getService(myContext, 0, i, 0);
```

Comment: Great! The reason is that reference to this is out of scope in new View.OnClickListener, so you need to remember it as a private member to the class